# Perform an action after jQuery .load

Tags: jquery, function

I need to perform an action after a jQuery .load call, currently this is my code:

```
function ajax_autopaginate(a, b) {

    function incrementPage () {
        next_page += 1;
        next_previews += 32;
    }

    jQuery('#' + b).load( a , incrementPage)
}
```

but I need to run incrementPage function only when .load is completed, how can I do this?

Comment: your code should work, can you tell us what's the problem with it?

Comment: you're right, my problem is that this function is often called when another instance of it is already running, now I have understood that that is my real problem, btw thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do it with the 'complete' callback, like so:

```
jQuery('#' + b).load(a , function() {
    incrementPage();
});
```

(tho the only problem i see in your snippet is the missing semicolon after the `load` declaration).

Comment: Still, shouldn't the OP's code have worked? After all, the callback function was passed in as a reference, so it should run at the same time as your anonymous callback runs.

Comment: correct, i was not paying attention. this should have worked, i edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @jmort253, can you also tell us whether a (the url) you pass is in the same domain as your html? If it's cross domain then it might not work as you expected.

Comment: I want to emphasise that I think this is more elegant than passing in the function reference. This leaves the door open for passing parameters in your callback function, should that ever be necessary.

Comment: @EliranMalka - I just saw the last part of your answer. The op's code looks correct. When passing in a function reference, you don't add a semicolon. It's just like passing in any other variable. It's similar to how you don't put a semicolon after the `a` variable or after the braces in your anonymous function. :) Your example is correct, but the part about the op's semicolon is actually incorrect and would generate a syntax error. Try running `function test(ttt) { ttt('hi'); };` in your Firebug, then run `test(alert);` and `test(alert;);`. The latter throws an "unexpected token ;" syntax err.

Comment: @jmort253 - technically, not. you should put a semicolon, tho the interpreter allows it if you don't. this, of course, is bad practice - we should not get used to omit semicolons at will.

Comment: @EliranMalka - I included my examples for clarity. If you're referring to `jQuery('#' + b).load( a , incrementPage)` needing a `;` at the end so it's `jQuery('#' + b).load( a , incrementPage);`, then yes, you're correct :) I interpreted what you were saying in the wrong way.

Comment: that's what i was referring indeed.